# angularjs directive for youtube video in iframe

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a directive to add a youtube video, title and description

Title and description work fine but i cant the video to work.

Not Found  Can't interpolate: {{video}} Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy. URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0

I tried using

```
scope.video  = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(attrs.video);
```

but still no luck

i have plunker example

http://plnkr.co/edit/EVGnYYdVR5Q5BWEsQVrl?p=preview

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an isolated scope with the `@` binding on `video` overwrites your setting of the `video` property in your link function.  Link only executes once before the bindings are applied.  You can use `$observe` to set the trusted url value and that will work even when the value is changed ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/SlEeJHfnKOotoKGTgFrx?p=preview)):

```
app.directive('youtubeHelp', function($sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: { header:'@' },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="well"><h2>{{header}}{{video}}...</h2></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.header = attrs.header;
        attrs.$observe('video', function(value) {
          scope.video = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value);
        })
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter like:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SVuNrNowVoZp4FzKmTKd?p=preview)

```
app.filter('trustUrl', function($sce) {
  return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
});

app.directive('youtubeHelp', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      header: '@',
      video: '@'
    },
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="well"><iframe ng-src="{{video | trustUrl}}"></iframe></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.header = attrs.header;
    }
  };
});
```